# While gcc needs -lm for math.h but no -l for includes stdio.h, stdlib.h etc

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I could not found any documentation on why `gcc` requires `-lm` for `math.h` functions but no `-l` is required for `stdio` or `stdlib` functions. Why some functions require the include and the `-l` `gcc` command option, and others don't require the `-l` option? Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know if it's part of the specification, but it's the traditional divide because on old systems the math function would otherwise take up a lot of space when they were not commonly used.

Comment: The functions in the includes `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h`, etc. almost all live in the same library, libc.

Comment: It's a bug, and you should complain about it to your vendor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some libraries which gets linked *by default*.

One of those default libraries for `gcc` is `libc.a` (static) or `libc.so` (dynamic) ([GNU standard C library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library)), and it contains the definition of `printf()` and `scanf()` families, including others, prototyped in `stdio.h` or `stdlib.h` .

Now, to answer your question, according to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)

> Under FreeBSD and Linux,<sup>[8]</sup> the mathematical functions (as declared in `math.h`) are bundled separately in the mathematical library `libm`. If any of them are used, the linker must be given the directive `-lm`.

If you want to check explicitly about the libraries getting linked by deafult, you need to use `-v` option to check them. You can also pass `-Wl,--verbose` option to get even more verbose output.

If you want to restrict the default linking, you can make use of `-nostdlib` switch.